# Alexa Skill Loop: Based off of User Input, Alexa will Say Something

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, alexa-skills-kit

**My skill:** Making a juice suggestion where when the user says a state, Alexa will give a juice suggestion based off of that state. The state and juice pair is stored into an array.

**Challenge:** Currently, my skill will only execute once. Is there a way where I can have a loop where after Alexa gives a suggestion, Alexa will ask the question again and wait for the user response? Attached is the code I have with my skill. Thanks.

```js
var Alexa = require('alexa-sdk');

const APP_ID = undefined;

const skillData = [
    {
        state: "FLORIDA",
        suggestion: "My suggestion for Florida is organic orange juice by Naked"
    },
    {
        state: "CALIFORNIA",
        suggestion: "My suggestion for California is pomegrante by POM!!"
    },
    {
        state: "NEW JERSEY",
        suggestion: "My suggestion for Jersey is blueberry by Jersey Fresh"
    }
];

var number = 0;
while(number<3){
var handlers = {
  'LaunchRequest': function () {

    this.emit(':ask', 'I can suggest a juice from any state in the United States. What state would you like a juice suggestion for?', 'Tell me a state name and I will suggest a local juice from there.');
  
      
    },
  'MakeSuggestion': function() {
      var stateSlot = this.event.request.intent.slots.state.value;

      this.emit(':tell', getSuggestion(skillData, 'state', stateSlot.toUpperCase()).suggestion);

  },
  'Unhandled': function () {
    this.emit(':tell', 'Sorry, I don\'t know what to do');
  },
  'AMAZON.HelpIntent': function () {
      this.emit(':ask', "What can I help you with?", "How can I help?");
  },
  'AMAZON.CancelIntent': function () {
      this.emit(':tell', "Okay!");
  },
  'AMAZON.StopIntent': function () {
      this.emit(':tell', "Goodbye!");
  },
}
number = number+1;
};

exports.handler = function(event, context){
  var alexa = Alexa.handler(event, context);
  alexa.registerHandlers(handlers);
  alexa.execute();
};

function getSuggestion(arr, propName, stateName) {
  for (var i=0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i][propName] == stateName) {
      return arr[i];
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `MakeSuggestion` function, use `ask` instead of `tell`, and append the question again:

```
this.emit(':ask', getSuggestion(skillData, 'state', stateSlot.toUpperCase()).suggestion + '. Tell me another state and I give you another suggestion!');
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this by using state and rather than using ":tell", you can respond  by ":ask" so that alexa mic remain open for user interaction.